# How to have "cvs update" ignore some folders that CVS is managing?

Tags: cvs

I have a system that uses CVS. Build takes a long time, partially because "CVS update" takes a long time. There are several folders that contain a lot of files that change rarely, if ever.
I would like to have "CVS update" ignore those folders (i.e. not even look at them).
I have tried .cvsignore and the -I options but they do not do what I want.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer comes with a caveat.  You really are not "supposed" to do stuff like this.

```
mv folder_to_ignore/CVS folder_to_ignore/CVS_ignored
```

This will not work for `cvs update -d` since this operation tricks CVS into thinking you have a partial checkout and since `cvs update -d` tries to checkout missing stuff.

To restore the folder to CVS control, rename:

```
folder_to_ignore/CVS_ignored
```

back to:

```
folder_to_ignore/CVS
```

Comment: I have to do `cvs update -d`. It would be too tricky not to do that. But thanks for your help anyway.